# Are C++ floating point constants always stored in static memory?

Tags: c++, floating-point, constants

In his book [Optimizing Software in C++](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) Agner Fog gives the following example:

> String constants and floating point constants are stored in static
>   memory. Example:
>
> ```
> // Example 7.2
> a = b * 3.5;
> c = d + 3.5;
> ```
>
> Here, the constant 3.5 will be stored in static memory. Most compilers
>   will recognize that the two constants are identical so that only one
>   constant needs to be stored.

Are all floating point constants **always** stored in static memory?

Why can't they be stored on the **stack**? Say in the example he gives.

Comment: Constants are simply part of the program code (similar to functions, etc ...)

Comment: How would they get on the stack? The value has to come from somewhere

Comment: It is implementation specific (depends upon the ABI, the processor, the compiler, the optimization flags)

Comment: The Stack is something you should understand prior to optimization.

Comment: @DieterLucking A couple of lines below he goes on to say, "Integer constants are usually included as part of the instruction code." So according to him floating points are *not* part of the program code.

Comment: the wording in the book is misleading. the compiler is not actually compelled to store the value 3.5 anywhere.

Comment: Well, they can be, the FLD1 and FLDZ instructions for example.  Definitely used by code generators, back when they still emitted FPU instructions.

Comment: @RichardHodges The text I quote is (obviously) out of the broader context to keep the question short. He does talk about optimization (the whole book is about it), and if the compiler optimizes constants away, then, obviously, they're not stored anywhere. It seems what he simply is saying is that when the compiler *does* store floating point constants, it stores them in *static* memory.

Comment: The architecture ABI might force the compiler to store floating point constants as part of the program code or it might force the compiler to store them with static data, or it might have more choices available.  The language standard makes no such assumptions at all.

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar There's only one other option (which applies to most integer constants), store them in .text. In principle float constants could be there. But the easiest way to get them back out is (unlike for integers, which can appear as immediate operand) to use a load from memory. That might as well be data memory then.

Comment: What does "static memory" mean as used here?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I took it to mean:  If you had declared `static const float x=3.5;` at module scope and then used `&x` the memory area that address would be within.  Assuming that is a more specific thing than "somewhere in memory" is itself a big ABI assumption, not language rule.  But if the ABI is such that the above is a specific thing, you still can't assume floating point constants are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the example. You are right that it stores the constants in the code when compiled with gcc for 64-bit mode with optimiztion off (-O0). It stores the constants in memory if you compile for 32-bit mode.

If you turn on optimization (-O3) then the calculations are simply optimized away because they are not used, and main just returns 0.

If you make a function that does some floating point calculations and returns a float or double, and compile with optimization on, then you will see that the floating point constants are stored in static memory.

I tried this:

```
float test(float x) {
    return x*0.9f + 3.1f;
}
```

g++ -c -S -O3 test.cpp

cat test.s

and got:

```
mulss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
addss   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
ret
```

where .LC0 and .LC1 are constants in the read-only data segment. The x86 and x86-64 instruction set has (unfortunately) no instruction that stores an immediate constant in a floating point register or vector register. It would have to first store the constant in general purpose registers and then transfer it to an xmm register, and this is not optimal (except for cases where there is heavy load on the data cache but not on the code cache).

Comment: "It would have to first store the constant in general purpose registers and then transfer it to an xmm register, and this is not optimal"


What makes this less optimal? Wouldn't the load from memory potentially be less optimal? Especially when you get into things like a vec3 where the compiler isn't necessarily going to have all those constants in the same cache lines

Comment: @ReDucTor: Yes, it would take an extra instruction to first put the constant into a general purpose register and then transfer it to an xmm register. On the other hand, you may avoid a data cache miss.

Comment: With a large program which has a reasonable number amount of data cache churn (A game), it seems like there is potential for a miss reasonably often, and when for something like a vec3 all three float values could be on completely different cache lines not anywhere near each other then it's potentially a miss for each. Unfortunately some basic testing with MSVC it looks like it didn't group floats used together in a group, clang appears to so it wouldn't suffer from multiple misses. It would be interesting to examine on a larger application how frequently data cache misses might be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple working example based on your pseudo-code:

```
int main()
{
  double b = 3.0;
  double d = 3.14;
  double a = b * 3.5;
  double c = d + 3.5;
  return 0;
}
```

Then compiled it:

```
g++ -O0 -o const const.cc
```

Then played with it in a debugger:

```
gdb const
...
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004ed <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004ee <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004f1 <+4>: movabs $0x4008000000000000,%rax
   0x00000000004004fb <+14>:    mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004ff <+18>:    movabs $0x40091eb851eb851f,%rax
   0x0000000000400509 <+28>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000000040050d <+32>:    movsd  -0x20(%rbp),%xmm1
   0x0000000000400512 <+37>:    movsd  0xae(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x4005c8
   0x000000000040051a <+45>:    mulsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x000000000040051e <+49>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400523 <+54>:    movsd  -0x18(%rbp),%xmm1
   0x0000000000400528 <+59>:    movsd  0x98(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x4005c8
   0x0000000000400530 <+67>:    addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000000400534 <+71>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400539 <+76>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040053e <+81>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000000000040053f <+82>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f1
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/sasha/stackoverflow/const 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004004f1 in main ()
(gdb) p  *(double*)0x4005c8
$2 = 3.5
```

So you see from all of this that constant 3.5 is stored at the address `0x4005c8` which is just 136 bytes after the end of `main`. The same address is used both times to references it, although it appears differently in the disassembly - first time as `0xae(%rip)`, second time as `movsd  0x98(%rip)`. This is because the value of `rip` keeps changing as the execution progresses - it is the instruction pointer.

With the help of `objdump -t` you can see that the above mentioned address falls into the `.rodata` section.

Note that  3.0 and 3.14 constants were encoded explicitly without a memory reference, per:

```
movabs $0x4008000000000000,%rax
```

and

```
movabs $0x40091eb851eb851f,%rax
```

Apparently since they are not repeated `gcc` decided it was not worth it to store them in memory.

UPDATE: As pointed out by JSF, the decision to not use a memory stored rather than immediate constant indeed depend on the usage. I verified that if I change `double d = 3.14` to `double d = b + 3.14` 3.14 becomes a memory reference.

I used `-O0` to keep things simple. With optimizations in such a simple example the assembly is optimized into something that achieves the same results but in a way that is too far removed from something useful enough to illustrate the point.

The answer, at least in the case of `gcc`, appears to be indeed "It depends". If you are curious, though, rather than just trusting a book or a blog post, it is better to make a simple example and take it apart - you get it straight from the horse's mouth, and you learn a whole lot more.

Comment: So the answer is, it depends?

Comment: Notice the very big difference between `double d = 3.14;` and `double c = d + 3.5;` and I **don't** mean the fact that 3.5 was used twice.  In x86_64 architecture, the compiler has a wider range of **practical** choices for a float constant that is simply stored into a variable than for one that is used in a float computation.  Of course, an optimizer might change either into the other.  But in the code you showed, the compiler chose a way of representing the constant to be simply stored that won't work for a constant to be directly used.

Comment: I disagree with your characterization of `-O0`, while optimizations often make the code "weird", `-O0` also causes dumb codegen, which is pointless verbose and does dumb things on purpose, and therefore doesn't give a representative impression. In reasonable code, that odd dance from a GPR through stack to XMM won't happen.

Comment: In optimized code that I look at, that "odd dance" is very common.  It won't happen in optimized trivial code.  But in complicated code, the path from the assignment of a constant to a local variable through use of that variable is often beyond the ability of the optimizer to sort out.

Comment: I'm not trusting anyone, or I wouldn't be asking the question. On the other hand, it's a well-known and respected book, so if something is misleading in it it's worth having a constructive criticism on it.

Comment: @Leo Heinsaar - you are trusting Stack Overflow if you just ask the question and read the answers, which you should always do with a grain of salt :-) It is good to ask questions, but you get more out of it when you try things out with your hands to supplement the reading. I learned some things I did not know through this exercise.

Comment: Sometimes "facts" in a textbook need to be narrowed and simplified or they are incomprehensible.  The choice of understandable but not perfectly accurate vs. exactly right and incomprehensible, can go either way in a well written text, and I would usually select informative over exact.  But in this case, the author blew it.  By the time you water that statement down enough to make it true it is useless information.  So exact is not the right choice.  But neither is incorrect.  The right choice was entirely skip this attempt to inform, because the only thing it does is misinform.

Comment: @SashaPachev How does it follow that I'm "trusting" StackOverflow if I "just ask the question and read the answers"? And what made you think I'm not trying things out myself?

Comment: @Leo Heinsaar - I am not saying you are not, I am just saying you should if you are not. And if you are, it would be good to post the results of your own hands-on research when asking a question. E.g. "I did this with compiler X, and got this, but I did not have compiler Y or others handy, does anybody know if this behavior is just the quirk of compiler X (the book seems to suggest it is), or are all compilers like that and the book is just plain wrong?"

Comment: @SashaPachev I don't like long questions.